# Using @ngrx/store in Angular2

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am working on sample application using Angular 2 and @ngrx/store(for state management)

When I execute below code I am not getting any error , but the expected
output is not displayed.

```
// EmployeeState.ts

export interface Employee {
                            id: number;
                            name: string;   
                            isActive: boolean;
                          }
```

// Feature Module es.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee.component';

import { Employee } from './EmployeeState';
import { EmpReducer } from './EmployeeReducer';

@NgModule({
           imports:[   RouterModule.forChild([
                       {path:'emp' , component: EmployeeComponent}
                       ]),
                       StoreModule.provideStore([{employee: EmpReducer}]),
                       CommonModule 
                   ],

           exports:[],
           providers:[],
           declarations:[EmployeeComponent]
})


 export class EsModule { }
```

EmployeeReducer.ts

```
import { Action , ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Employee } from './EmployeeState';

var emp: Employee = { id: 1 , name: 'testname' , isActive: true };

export const EmpReducer : ActionReducer<Employee> = ( state: Employee = emp ,    action: Action) => {
 return state;
}
```

employee.component.ts

```
import { Component , ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Employee } from './EmployeeState';

interface AppState {
    employee: Employee;
 }

 @Component({
               selector:'',
               template: `
               <h2> Employee name is: {{emp$.name | async}}</h2>
              `
  })


 export class EmployeeComponent {

    emp$: Observable<Employee>;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.emp$ = this.store.select<Employee>('employee');
    }

  }
```

when EmployeeComponent gets displayed  I was expecting output to be "Employee name is: testname" but instead it is only "Employee name is:" .
Any idea what is the issue in this code.

Comment: Try `{{(emp$ | async)?.name}}`

Comment: @ cartant still the same output

Comment: @cartant I implemented his code and that was the **only** bug. The output in chrome is `testname`. @CleanCrispCode please save changes in your ide and call `ng sevre(for angular cli)/npm start` agian.

Comment: Yes , it's working now..